# Is contact of two continuous function also continuous to a parameter?

Tags: continuity, epsilon-delta

I have two continuous function $f(x;\alpha)$ and $g(x;\alpha)$ that are continuous on $x \in [0,1]$ for any $\alpha \in [a,b]$.

Furthermore, $f(x;\alpha)$ and $g(x;\alpha)$ are both continuous on $\alpha$ for any $x$.

Suppose there is always a unique contact $x^{*}(\alpha)$ for any $\alpha$ such that $f(x^{*}(\alpha);\alpha)=g(x^{*}(\alpha);\alpha)$

How can I show that $x^{*}(\alpha)$ is continuous on $\alpha$?

Comment: Is $g(x;\alpha)$ continuous in $\alpha$ also?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question.

Comment: What do you mean by a "contact"? Does it satisfy $f(x^*(\alpha),\alpha) = g(x^*(\alpha),\alpha)$ ?

Comment: My apologies again. Yes, and I edited the question again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not necessarily continuous.

Consider, for $0 < \alpha \le 1$, the piecewise-linear function
$f(x;\alpha)$ whose graph consists of straight lines from $(0,1)$ to $(\alpha/2, 0)$
to $(\alpha, 1)$ to $(1,\alpha)$.  For $\alpha = 0$ we take $f(x;0) = 1-x$.  Note that
$f(x;0) = \lim_{\alpha \to 0+} f(x;\alpha)$ for every $x \in [0,1]$, so this does satisfy the requirements of continuity in $x$ and in $\alpha$ (although it is not **jointly** continuous in $x$ and $\alpha$).  Take $g(x;\alpha) = 0$.  Then we have
$x^*(\alpha) = \alpha/2$ for $\alpha > 0$, but $x^*(0) = 1$.

EDIT: To make it more explicit: for $\alpha > 0$,
$$ f(x;\alpha) = \cases{1-\frac{2x}{\alpha} & for $0 \le x \le \alpha/2$\cr
                        \frac{2x}{\alpha} - 1 & for $\alpha/2 \le x \le \alpha$\cr
                        1+\alpha-x & for $\alpha \le x \le 1$} $$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Would you mind clarifying the first sentence of straight lines?

Comment: You mean that I should check if joint-continuity on $(x,\alpha)$ can be another assumption needed to guarantee the result.

Comment: Yes, if $f$ and $g$ are jointly continuous the result is true.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate it!